# what is the difference between curl --upload-file and curl --form file=@filename

Tags: curl, file-upload

What is the difference between `curl --upload-file` and `curl --form file=@/path/file`? How the HTTP request be different for these?

Answer (score 5):

## --upload-file

(with a HTTP or HTTPS URL) makes curl send an [HTTP PUT request](https://everything.curl.dev/http/put).

### --form

makes curl send a HTTP POST request with a [multipart formpost](https://everything.curl.dev/http/multipart) body.